# Postgresql : Inserting data into int array fails with index row size 2840 exceeds maximum

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Inserting more entries into int array causes the column index to complain:

> Query failed: ERROR: index row size 2840 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "vx_index" HINT: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

But the recommended solution doesn't work with my int array column because the md5 function expects strings.

```
CREATE INDEX vx_index ON matching_tariffs USING GIN(md5(vx));
ERROR:  function md5(integer[]) does not exist
```

How should I create such index?